# Делегироваие доменов с

Tags: devops, cloudflare

Имею домен который привязан к CloudFlare, но я должен делегировать его для того чтобы его могли настраивать в beget. Тут нужно прописывать ns записи, записи прописал а он все еще привязан к CloudFlare. Кто сталкивался как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете:

1. или прописать у регистратора NS записи CloudFlare и в нем прописать A-запись сервера Beget
2. или прописать NS записи Beget и уже там прописать А-запись

На распространение DNS зоны при смене NS записей может потребоваться до 3-х суток